# How to make transparent WPF app without making it click-through?

Tags: c#, wpf

Can you please show me how can I make a transparent window in WPF without making it click-through? I've been struggling with this for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the usual `AllowsTransparency="True"` and `WindowStyle="None"` for custom window layout, add `Background="#01FFFFFF"` on your Window. Any parts that are not explicitly drawn will appear as (almost) transparent (there will be a very faint shadow against dark backgrounds) but those regions will capture mouse clicks, preventing click through to other windows.

The following is an example of how to create a non-rectangular window with a hollow portion

**HollowView.xaml**

```
<Window
    x:Class="CustomWindowChromeDemo.HollowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="#01ffffff"
    WindowStyle="None">

    <Grid
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Path
            Data="F0 M 0,0 L 10,0 L 5,10 z M 4,2 A 1,1 0 0 0 3,3 L 3,4 A 1,1 0 0 0 4,5 L 6,5 A 1,1 0 0 0 7,4 L 7,3 A 1,1 0 0 0 6,2 z"
            Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}"
            StrokeThickness="4" />

        <TextBlock
            Margin="0,20,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="16"
            Text="Click+Drag to move ..." />

        <Button
            Margin="0,0,0,80"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Click="CloseButtonClick"
            Content="Close" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**HollowView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class HollowView
{
    public HollowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MouseLeftButtonDown += (s, e) => DragMove();
    }

    private void CloseButtonClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
private void btnShowHollowWindow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var hollowView = new HollowView
    {
        Width = 300,
        Height = 300,
        Owner = this,
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner
    };

    hollowView.ShowDialog();
}
```

For more detail on custom windows layout in WPF, check out my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-custom-window-chrome/).

Comment: Any way I can make drawings fully visible?

Comment: @SpaghettiChef I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: Well, thanks for taking your time. I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried you solution and added some to it. Now it's working just fine.